# Java - Matching specific sentence pattern and if element is missing raise an error

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to be able to search for a specific pattern in a string and then add each string to a different list, which follows something along the following:

```
List<String> string1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> string2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> int1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> int2 = new ArrayList<>();
//Note: Pattern I want = string string: int, int
String str = "2 someword 3 word anotherword: 7, 5"; //find the substring which matches the pattern (note there is a ':' after the second word and a ',' after the first integer)
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); i++) {
    //if the front 3 (i+1, i+2, i+3) are word, int, int then string1.add(splitted.get(i))
    //do similar for the 2nd: check(i-1, i+1, i+2) and add to str2
    //do similar for the 3rd: check(i-2, i-1, i+2) add to int1
    //do similar for the 4th: check(i-3, i-2, i-1) add to int2
}

//then System.out.println for all all 4 lists
```

**Expected Result**

```
[word] //splitted.get(3)
[anotherword] //splitted.get(4)
[7] //splitted.get(5)
[5] //splitted.get(6)
```

Up to this point I am fine, assuming in the string, there exists a substring which matches the pattern, by using the regex `\\d+` and `[a-zA-Z]+`. However, in the case that I get the following:

```
String str = "2 someword 3 word anotherword: , 5" //Note: the 1st integer is missing and is replaced with an empty space
```

I want it to register the missing integer as a fact that it is missing from this specific pattern of: `string string: int, int` and then return an error.

**Edit:**
The pattern I want is:

```
"string string: int, int"
```

Comment: `//find the substring which matches the pattern`. What pattern?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Its: `string string: int, int`

Comment: I think this is your homework and you are trying to find the answer here?

Comment: I guess. Its sort of a dumbed down version of a part of what I want in the end. Here, I just want to figure out how to use a pattern to search within a string since I couldn't find a tutorial on using patterns for a long string (only regex for individular words which i've already implemented). Not to find an answer to my assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pattern is `string string: int, int` and string is `2 someword 3 word anotherword: 7, 5`, then this program does what you need :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "2 someword 3 word anotherword: 7, 5";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) (\\w+:) (\\d+), (\\d+)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String word = matcher.group(1);
        String anotherword = matcher.group(2);
        String str7 = matcher.group(3);
        String str5 = matcher.group(4);
        System.out.println(word+" "+anotherword+" "+str7+" "+str5);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
word anotherword: 7, 5
```

Comment: Should the regex have group for the matcher to work ? `(\\w+) (\\w+): (\\d+), (\\d+)`

Comment: Why do you need groups?

Comment: For your while loop ?

Comment: It works without groups in regex. `matcher.group()` returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

Comment: So what `Pattern` actually does is like an advanced version of `String.matches(regex)`? Also, for the `Matcher` part, what is `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str)` setting `matcher` to be equal to? Since it doesn't look like it sets it to be a string since that's being done in `String group = matcher.group();`

Comment: Method find() finds the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern

Comment: @Yuxie, you first compile a `Pattern` using a regex (#3), you then get a Matcher (the result) from this pattern for a String `str`. On each loop, you will get a capturing group (here the full pattern since they are none).

Comment: @JaySmith, yes but if you pay attention to the code provided, OP expect to get each value in a distinct list, so you need groups. Since OP don't seems to know Regex and Pattern, you should at least try to explain that part.

Comment: Edited answer to include groups

Answer (score 0):

Change `"\\s+"`to `",\\s+|:\\s+|\\s+"`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.